# create user only for one instance on google cloud engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I need to create a user for only one instance on gce.

I use centos 6.7 image.

I create on instance my user with `adduser` command, then I try to connect over ssh using `gcloud`

```
gcloud compute ssh my-user@instance-name
```

with this command google create a project user that is able to connect to all instances.

Is there a way to create a user only for an instance using `gcloud`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use VM instance custom metadata (Not project metadata) and [apply your user's SSH key only to a specific VM instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys#instance-only).

```
gcloud compute instances add-metadata example-instance \
--metadata-from-file ssh-keys=user-ssh-key.pub
```

This can be done via Google Cloud Console as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the gcloud settings from Google Cloud Console -> Permissions -> User Accounts

The new unix accounts will also have to be created on your local machine(s)

To solve your need to partition separate users per instance you could give each instance its own google cloud project ... this would give easier security and privacy isolation we well as deployment devops simplicity especially regarding freedom to add/drop instances post initial app deploy

Comment: The user will be created for all instance. I need a user only for a single instance